# Set a custom shipping rate cost calculated on cart total weight in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In Woocommerce I have installed a shipping plug in but it calculates shipping per item in cart instead of per order total.

What I need is to calculate the shipping cost this way:
- First kg is $5 
- And $1 by kilo for all others.

Is it possible to do it?

With the plugin if there is 2 items in cart of 1 kg each, it calculates the shipping as 2 x $5 = $10 
Instead what I should need is: **$5** *(first kilo)* + **$1** *(additional kilo)* = **$6** *(for 2 kg)*.

I have no response from plugin developer, so looking for work around.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried as your work around?

Comment: I am asking for work around or solution. I am asking for code to add to my plugin.php so that cart is submitted as combined total.  thank you

Comment: oops, what happened to my question - someone edited it? I cannot make sense of the edit now. I want to know how to get my plugin to calculate the shipping based on total weight in the cart instead of on each product in the cart....

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATED:** You don't need any plugin *(so you can remove it)*.

To get a shipping rate calculated on total cart weight, with:

- an initial amount of $5 (for the first kilo)
- a variable rate of $1 for each additional kilo

Do the following:

**1) Settings in WooCommerce:** 
For all your "Flat rate" shipping method *(in each shipping zone)*, set a cost of **`1`** *(amount by kilo)*.

[image]

So the cost

> *(Once done disable/save and enable/save to refresh woocommerce transient cache)*

**2) Custom code** *(as the shipping unit cost is $1 by kilo, we add 4 kilos to total cart weight in the calculations to set the correct cost)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_delivery_flat_rate_cost_calculation', 10, 2 );
function custom_delivery_flat_rate_cost_calculation( $rates, $package )
{
    // The total cart items  weight
    $cart_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();

    foreach($rates as $rate_key => $rate_values){
        $method_id = $rate_values->method_id;
        $rate_id = $rate_values->id;
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $method_id ) {
            ##  SHIPPING COSTS AND TAXES CALCULATIONS ##
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost = $rates[$rate_id]->cost*($cart_weight+4);
            foreach ($rates[$rate_id]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){
                    $tax_cost = number_format( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key]*($cart_weight+4));
                    $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] = $tax_cost;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works on woocommerce versions 2.6.x and 3+

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The reason we are using the plug in is because there are so many variables to calculate the shipping price based on weight and location with several services being offered such as overnight, road etc, these are defined in an API - not sure if am getting this correct...

Comment: I'd like to insert an image of how the current code looks like  - how do I insert image (ctrl G not working..

Comment: @linda I you choose a plugin, you are prisoner of what the plugin allow you to do. In general this is something closed. So Using the plugin will not allow you to get what you want… and nobody is going to really help you in that case.